# ejs how to send a variable to sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, ejs

I'm making a node js express application. and i use ejs as my template engine.
in one of my ejs files i have a tree view. this tree view has an event for when something changes in it. i use this event to get the structure of the treeview.

```
$('#tree').on("changed.jstree", async function (e, data) {
                    var v = $('#tree').jstree(true).get_json('#', {flat:true});
                    var mytext = JSON.stringify(v);
                });
```

This works fine and iget the data i want. but i also want to send it to my database. for this i use sequelize. 
I first tried this to update my database:

```
                $('#tree').on("changed.jstree", async function (e, data) {
                    var v = $('#tree').jstree(true).get_json('#', {flat:true});
                    var mytext = JSON.stringify(v);
                    <%- world.treeData = v%>
                });
```

world is passed from my index.js file where al my routes are. but ejs cannot acces the v variable becous ejs is runned before javascript is.
So I need a way to get this v variable to my database. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very big misunderstanding of the relationship between client and server. EJS cannot "send" anything anywhere- I'ts just a templating engine. It constructs an HTML string dynamically, which is later used by Express to be sent to your browser, as an HTML document(along side JS files/code of course). After that, EJS "ceases" to exist, so to speak.

In order to send data from your JS event listener, you need to perform an AJAX request to some endpoint in your server, which will then use Sequelize to store it in the DB. I'll give you an example:

Let's say you want to register a new user. Your JS:

```
$('#tree').on("changed.jstree", async function (e, data) {//Let's say you want to register a new user.
    var v = $('#tree').jstree(true).get_json('#', { flat: true });
    var newUserData = JSON.stringify(v);
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/user', {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: newUserData,
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
});
```

Your express route, where this request is handled:

```
app.post('/user', async function (req, res) {
    try {

        const newUserData = req.body;

        const createdUser = await UserModel.create(newUserData)//This is where Sequelize comes into picture.

        res.json({id:createdUser.id})


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }

})
```